# How to get a tree structure from Entity Framework's model metadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a dynamic reports generator that allows end-user to basically create his own SELECT statements using Entity Framework models. Let me start with a description of what I'm trying to achieve exactly:

1. User selects an entity (e.g. 'Student'),
2. He gets a list which contains entity properties ('FirstName', 'LastName' etc. along with their type) and related entities ('Enrollments'). Primary and foreign key properties are NOT INCLUDED,
3. On this list, related entities act like directories, user can click on them to display their properties and related entities in a tree structure,
4. User can select any property (it will later be required to create a dynamic SELECT statement).

I was thinking about using reflection to do this, this seems to be a relatively simple way, but there are limitations (like determining if a property is a foreign key). I know there is also MetadataWorkspace class, but it is very confusing to me, never used it before. I also need to mention, that I'm aware of potential reference loops, therefore there will be a depth limit for related entities. How can I create such entity relations tree?

**Additional info**

I forgot to mention, that this project I'm doing would be a reusable library, so It should work with any dbContext, preferrably (if possible) without need to modify the models or adding attributes.

Comment: You can create your own attributes, or there are attributes that mark foreign keys (aka `ForeignKeyAttribute`).

Comment: This project: https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/ helped me a lot when I needed something like that. And you'll need a bunch of reflection in addition.

Comment: Ron's solution would be ok, but requires use of attributes which may not be the best option if already using conventions. However, @trailmax link seems useful, i will take a closer look later. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Some guidelines for your development:

- The method below can extract all the class properties of your Models:

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ExtractTypeProperties(Type type)
  {
      return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                             BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
  }
  ```
- Navigation properties usually are `virtual`. You can use something like this to get these properties:

  ```
  foreach (var property in typeof(MyModel).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)) { ... }
  ```
- Model primary keys usually have the names `Id`, `TheModelId` or are decorated with [`[Key]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx);
- Model foreign keys usually have associated navigation properties with the same name, except for the `Id` suffix, or they are decorated with [`[ForeignKey]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that navigation properties also can be decorated with this attribute, so I think you'll have to make a double-check to satisfy all the conventions;
- Avoid to reflect the selected object from EF itself, because EF replaces the navigation properties by dynamic proxies. Prefer to reflect the class type.